# Diminished and augmented scales

Tags: theory, scales

I know that the augmented scale has a sharpened 4th and 5th, and a diminished scale has a flattened 3rd and 5th, but doesn't a diminished scale have other flats in it as well? Could someone please go into greater detail as to how and why the diminished and augmented scales are formed the way they are, and also what modes they relate to? Also, is a half-diminished scale just a diminished scale with a minor seventh or is it even a scale at all? Sorry for all the questions, just please try and go into deeper detail about everything with augmented and diminished scales.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of there isn't an "official" augmented scale. What people typically refer to as "the augmented scale" is actually a scale known as the Lydian Augmented scale which is built from the third mode of the ascending melodic minor scale.

**Lydian Augmented Mode from A Melodic Minor**

```
C  D  E  F♯  G♯  A  B  C
```

**The "Diminished Scale"** is either **whole-half step** or **half-whole step** repeating intervallic patterns. These are called *octatonic scales* because they have eight notes; these scales are symmetrical - they repeat at the interval of a minor third.

**Half-Whole Diminished Scale**

```
C  D♭  E♭  E  G♭  G   A  B♭   C
```

The chord would that goes with this: `C7b9` or `Eb7b9` or `Gb7b9` or `Bb7b9`... notice the minor thirds between the roots.

Why a dominant chord for the diminished you ask? Because when you have a scale that has both a minor and a major third, the minor third is notated a `#9`.

The `Db = b9`,

the `Eb = #9`

`E = Major 3rd`

**Whole-Half Diminished Scale**

```
C  D  Eb  F  Gb  Ab  A  B  C
```

The chord would that goes with this: `C°` or `Eb°` or `Gb°` or `A°`... again, notice the minor thirds between the roots.

The half diminished scale  mode of the ascending melodic minor scale starting  on the 6th scale degree which in C looks like this:

```
C  D  E♭  F  G♭  A♭  B♭   C
```

Comment: Your half-whole scale is heptatonic; it misses an E. It is also worth mentioning that the "half diminished scale" is usually (and better) called "Locrian ♮2".

Comment: Is there a rule for the spelling of notes for the dim. scales?

Comment: @Tim as far as I know, it goes by the same rules as if you were putting notes to a prime row where you would just use all sharps or all flats. In the context of an actual piece I would base it on the harmony to spell the notes used correctly.

Comment: Okay, thank you for clarifying. The diminished scales all make good sense to me now. But Why is it called Lydian augmented if it starts on the 3rd scale degree instead of the fourth? Wouldn't it be Phryggian? @Dom

Comment: @CaineDodson that only applies to Major. This scale is called lydian augmented because it is a lydian scale with an augmented 5th.

Comment: @Dom What about this augmented scale? https://youtu.be/T5SmcH11kUk?t=30m20s `1` `#2` `M3` `P5` `#5` `M7`. This differs from the Lydian Augmented scale

Comment: @KolobCanyon the lydian augmented scale much is better known that that scale and that scale is rather awkwardly named that since it's two triads superimposed. I'd consider the whole tone scale as more augmented in nature than that scale.

Comment: @Dom It's confusing because people use the term "Augmented" scale freely, but there really isn't any rhyme or reason other than the root triad being augmented quality :( ... I'm fine with that answer because you are absolutely right in saying it is much more common.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you guys have gotten it right about the Augmented Scale. 
The formula should be Root, Minor 3rd, Major 3rd, Perfect 5th, Minor Sixth, Major Seventh, Octave.

So a C Augmented scale would go: C D# E G Ab B C and as there's only 6 tones in the scale before we come to the root again, it's a Hexatonic Scale.

The Diminished scale(s) have (as other people mentioned) the Whole-Half tone movements or the Half-Whole tone movements throughout the scale, so a C Diminished (Whole-Half) would be C D Eb F Gb Ab A B C

&

the Diminished (Half-Whole) would be C Db Eb Fb Gb G A Bb C, making them Octatonic Scales.

Comment: More technically - C aug. scale - C Eb E G G# B - it's two aug triads, C E G# and Eb G B. The second is a min 3rd away, or possible an aug 2nd, making it D# Fx Ax. I like the simpler first!

Comment: Skoven's augmented scale consists of two augmented triads correctly spelt: G B D# and Ab C E.

Comment: Skoven's scale also has only one instance of each given pitch, instead of having two types of Es *and* two types of Gs.